# How to avoid code duplication in Rails Sidekiq schedule job and worker with the same code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I've got Sidekiq worker `SyncProductsWorker` which calls inside the controller action:

```
class ProductsController < BaseApiController
  def fetch_all
    ::Imports::FetchAllProductsWorker.perform_async

    head :ok
  end
end
```

And Sidekiq job `FetchAllProductsJob` with the same code as `SyncProductsWorker` as a schedule job inside `sidekiq.yml`

`sidekiq.yml`

```
:queues:
  - imports_fetch_all
:dynamic: true
:schedule:
  imports_fetch_all_job:
    cron: '0 0 * * *' # at midnight
    class: Imports::FetchAllProductsJob
    queue: imports_fetch_all
```

So basically both classes, worker and job looks almost the same:

```
# worker
module Imports
  class FetchAllProductsWorker
    include Sidekiq::Worker
    sidekiq_options queue: 'imports_fetch_all'

    def perform
      puts 'test'
    end
  end
end

# schedule job
module Imports
  class FetchAllProductsJob < ApplicationJob
    sidekiq_options queue: 'imports_fetch_all'

    def perform
      puts 'test'
    end
  end
end
```

How to avoid code duplication to not have two files with the same code?

Comment: If you're just talking about code duplication, you avoid this the same way you avoid it anywhere: Either have one place call the other, or factor it out to a 3rd place and call that place from your original two sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to talk to Sidekiq directly in one place, and ActiveJob in another place. Both places can just talk directly to the ActiveJob job. Delete your Sidekiq worker, and replace your call to the worker's `perform_async` with a call to the job's [`perform_later`](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#enqueue-the-job):

```
  def fetch_all
    ::Imports::FetchAllProductsJob.perform_later

    head :ok
  end
```